# GCC does not warn about conversion and loss of data

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I was fiddling around with GCC 4.9.2 on windows and noticed it does not warn about conversion from double to int, while the visual studio compiler does:

The code:

```
int main()
{   
    int celsius, fahrenheit, kelvin;
    celsius = 21;
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
    kelvin = celsius + 273.15; //here it should warn!

    printf("%d C = %d F = %d K", 
        celsius, fahrenheit, kelvin);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled using:

```
gcc hello.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99
```

I compiled the same code with visual studio compiler:

```
C:\temp>cl hello.c /nologo /W4 /FeC2f.exe
hello.c
hello.c(14): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [-Wconversion](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) flag, with that `gcc` warns:

```
warning: conversion to 'int' from 'double' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
 kelvin = celsius + 273.15; //here it should warn!
```

Why isn't it enabled with `-Wall` or `-Wextra`, is covered in the linked wiki which says:

> Implicit conversions are very common in C. This tied with the fact
>   that there is no data-flow in front-ends (see next question) results
>   in hard to avoid warnings for perfectly working and valid code.
>   Wconversion is designed for a niche of uses (security audits, porting
>   32 bit code to 64 bit, etc.) where the programmer is willing to accept
>   and workaround invalid warnings. Therefore, it shouldn't be enabled if
>   it is not explicitly requested.

Comment: Interesting, I thought `/Wall` and or `/Wextra` would take care of that as well